# Are there any commands for weather and time in MC:PE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I change the weather and time of day in Minecraft Pocket Edition? I have version 0.13.0 and I want to know if there are any commands that can help me. If so, what are they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make it always night time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294816/can-i-make-it-always-night-time) + [How can I change the weather?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283622/how-can-i-change-the-weather/283624#283624)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Minecraft: Pocket Edition does not support any in-game commands for the time being, therefore there are no commands for changing weather or time.

There is a mod for Pocket Edition, however, that adds commands in Single Player mode, and one command in it allows you to set the in-game time, though there does not seem to be one for weather. The mod is not even updated yet for 0.13.0.

The only way to do so might be with an external world-editing app, provided that you're using Android (don't know if iOS has them).