# How do you clear the weather in MINECRAFT Pe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

It keeps raining and destroying my house so how do I use the command to turn off the rain?
Please I'm getting frustrated

Comment: Wait...rain is destroying your house? What are you building it out of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any commands for weather and time in MC:PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245475/are-there-any-commands-for-weather-and-time-in-mcpe)

Answer (score 1):

The command `/gamerule doweathercycle false` stops the weather from changing. If you then do `/weather clear`, it should always be clear weather.

Comment: Do you mean `/gamerule doweathercycle false`? No Minecraft game has `/doweathercycle` as a command.

Comment: Also, the `doweathercycle` gamerule, although existing as `doWeatherCycle` on the PC/Java edition, does not exist in Minecraft: Pocket Edition.

Comment: Yes, whoops! And the gamerule does exist in pe, not sure which version, I'm currently in the beta testing builds.

Answer (score -1):

If your are using `Android` to play `Minecraft PE` then you can use `PocketInvEditor` which lets you enable and disable lots of settings you previously didn't have access to. However, if you are playing on `Windows Phone OS`, or `iOS`, then you might be out of luck!

This tutorial shows you how to use PocketInvEditor successfully:

Comment: How would you go about using said application to accomplish the goal?  It's all well and good to suggest a program, but it doesn't really help if you don't detail how to use the program to do what the asker wants.

Comment: It is self explanatory and they are surely clever enough to type into Google "How to use PocketInvEditor", my 5 year old cousin used it without any help from anyone, so they should be able to. @Frank

Comment: If you don't want to add instructions, you don't have to, but be aware that until you do, this will be considered a low quality answer.

Comment: Videos don't count.  You need to add actual instructions.  What happens if the video gets removed?  Then your explanation is no longer useful.  That's why we prefer text over video, whenever possible.