# Can I make it always night time?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like my world to be always night time, but there appears to be no option to change this. So is it possible to make it always night on my world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that as of the 1.1 update "The Discovery Update" (June 1st, 2017), it is possible with the gamerule `doDaylightCycle`. The command:

```
/gamerule doDaylightCycle false
```

will stop the cycle from day to night and night to day.  Just use it when it is night.  I believe that will do the trick.

Comment: Happy to help!  I was looking for this solution too and this was one of the first google results.  Figured I'd post what I found to help you, and anyone else looking for this solution as well :)

Comment: If this answer is more helpful to you than the current accepted answer, @sun-solar-arrow, you can mark it as accepted instead.

Comment: @Fabian ok, I'll accept this answer

Answer (score 6):

As of 0.16.0, you can change the time to night one time by

```
/time set night
```

To make it night constantly, (or if you are on lower versions then 0.16) you can use a mod:

- [Simple Commands mod](http://for-minecraft.com/mods-for-minecraft-pocket-edition/955-simple-commands-mod-for-minecraft-pe-0111.html)

  > Simple Commands mod adds a few new, simple text commands. Now, among the "standard" commands will have a new command that has the effect to your character. In total there are 23 different effects, such as speed and invisibility - it is the effects of potions. With these commands, you can affect the gamegame mode, weather, time, deceleration time, set the level of experience, and more in MCPE 0.11-0.15.7
- [pocketInvEditor mod](http://minecraftpecheats.com/2014/01/09/how-to-turn-night-mode-on-in-creative-mode-minecraft-pocket-edition/) (available on Google Play)

  > PocketInvEditor is an inventory editor for Minecraft Pocket Edition. With this tool, you can give yourself more blocks and items without writing a single hexadecimal digit or connecting to a computer.

  - the mod also allows locking the day/night cycle

Answer (score 2):

Not possible without a mod. This is a good one:

http://mcpeuniverse.com/mods/always-night/

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a repeating command block and type in `/time set night` and let it be active, but run `/gamerule commandblockoutput false` first before you can activate it. If you don't run it, you will get bugged from the amount of lines outputted by the command block (unless you're okay with it).